# Rename Typescript files with suffixes support in IntelliJ

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

When you try to rename an Angular feature in IntelliJ / WebStorm, the refactor tool proposes you a naming respecting Angular convention. For example, `StuffComponent` => `BetterStuffComponent` get the file renamed `stuff.component.ts` => `better-stuff.component.ts`, preserving the `.component.ts` suffix.

However, when renaming a custom file, IntelliJ proposes another convention : `StuffForm` => `BetterStuffForm` get the following proposition : `stuff.form.ts` => `better-stuff-form.ts`

Is there a way to configure the renaming suggestion pattern in IntelliJ / WebStorm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting `Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript > Code Generation > Naming conventions: Dash case with suffix` might help.